# Debug jQueryUI Versions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

Within my Rails project, my old jQuery code for sorting a list of `<li>` elements has broken. The logged error is:

```
TypeError: $.ui.isOverAxis is not a function
```

I think the culprit is that an unwanted, older version of *jquery-ui.js* (v1.9.2) is making it into my headers, and I don't know how to remove it.

The unwanted jQuery file is originating from the `jquery-rails` gem. I don't understand why, since I've removed the `//= require jquery-ui` line from my *application.js* file.

Here is my current *application.js* file:

```
//= require moment.min.js
//= require nicEdit.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require_tree .
```

My Gemfile is updated to the most recent versions of the `jquery-rails` gem (2.2.1) and the `jquery-ui-rails` gem (4.0.3).

Yet an older version of jquery (1.9.2) appears in my header files in development mode:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1"></script>
```

Through debugging in development mode, I can tell that the *jquery-ui.js* file comes from the `jquery-rails` gem.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I have updated the question to reflect my discovery that the *jquery-ui.js* file is, in fact, coming from the `jquery-rails` gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that ActiveAdmin is calling `//= require jquery-ui`, which is in turn pulling in the *jquery-ui.js* file from `jquery-rails`.

That file is clobbering the version of jQueryUI from `jquery-ui-rails`.

The long-term solution might be for `jquery-rails` to remove the *jquery-ui.js* file, or at least rename it.

In the short-term, I solved my problem by removing `//= require jquery.ui.all` and relying entirely on `jquery-rails`, skipping `jquery-ui-rails` altogether.