# Ruby on Rails: "couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just done a fresh install and was able to access the default rails page at localhost:3000, but when I installed the activeadmin gem I had a problem when accessing /admin/ and received the following error on /admin/login (I was redirected, but this is what I saw on the page:)

What do I do? I have done bundle update and it's not fixed it.

Here's the partial error message:

> Sprockets::FileNotFound in Active_admin/devise/sessions#new
>
> Showing /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activeadmin->0.6.0/app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb where line #12 raised:
>
> couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'
>    (in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activeadmin->0.6.0/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js:2)

here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'activeadmin'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: show your application.js file

Comment: @uDaY: active_admin uses its own manifest - the application.js file shouldn't matter here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2232) due to the `jquery-rails` dependency dropping jQuery-UI support.  The workaround for the moment appears to be to force the `jquery-rails` gem to load using version 2.3.0:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'
```

A related problem due to this: [Debug jQueryUI Versions in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802515/debug-jqueryui-versions-in-rails).

Comment: @markhorrocks: Then it's probably not the same cause - feel free to ask a question regarding the problem you are experiencing

Comment: If you're in my shoes and this didn't work: make sure you don't have the gem `jrails` installed, it will conflict with `jquery-rails` with no helpful error to tell you so.  I was upgrading to Rails 3.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using later versions of jquery-ui-rails in my case **jquery-ui-rails-5.0.0**

I found out in the jquery-ui-rails-5.0.0 assets folder, that writing the following line into your application.css:

```
*= require jquery-ui
```

fetches all ui elements for your css, it simply calls:

```
*= require jquery-ui/all
```

and if you write the following into your application.js

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

it fetches most jquery js files, with exception of some specific datepickers, there is no #all method for jquery in application.js, in most cases these would do, but if not, then you can add the rest diretcly into applications.js e.g

```
//=require jquery-ui/datepicker-ru
```

So in summary to use all ui for both css and js

```
*= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui
```

Comment: Resolved my issue, as I upgraded the jquery-ui-rails to 5.0.0 . Thanks

Comment: This worked for me. Pay attention to the 'dashes' in this answer (i.e "jquery.ui" should be "jquery-ui", as this answer correctly indicates).

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest updating your `application.js` from: `//= require jquery_ui` to `//= require jquery.ui.all` as the preferable solution (rather than using an outdated version of the gem).

Comment: As the OP stated, this is occuring within the /admin namespace due to the manifest in active_admin.  Modifying application.js won't help - you would need to copy over the active_admin asset tree and make the modifications there.  That's fairly intrusive and quite a headache to maintain for updates.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the jquery-ui-rails gem will also give you jquery.ui support.

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

In your application.js and application.css files, you can add all modules

```
jquery.ui.all
```

or only the ones you need, e.g.:

```
jquery.ui.slider
```

Comment: Correct - There's new syntax to include jquery ui. 

Use `//= require jquery.ui.all` to include all modules, or you could specify just the core with `//= require jquery.ui.core`

more info at [jquery-ui-rails gem page][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails

Comment: I think that Roger's comment is now out of date (as of Aug 2014) on Rails 4.1.

Comment: Yep! New [syntax](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails#require-everything) is now `//= require jquery-ui`.