# Error after run heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

**I already ran "heroku pg:reset DATABASE".However,I still got this error.**

---

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8257
==  AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrating =======================================
-- add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "password_digest" character varying(255)/app/ve
ndor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adap
ters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:425:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifi
cations/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:420:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:360:in `add_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:379:in `add_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:625:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:597:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:597:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:617:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20130822145844_add_password_digest_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:571:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:554:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:553:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:709:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:959:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:1005:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connecti
on_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/transact
ions.rb:209:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:1005:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:958:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:920:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:916:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:916:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:764:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/migratio
n.rb:742:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railties
/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

---

Any suggestion?

Comment: `PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist` << you're missing the `users` table. Run `rake db:create`?

Comment: i just had a problem similar to this.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412099/heroku-open-fails-table-doesnt-exist-error-in-logs

Answer (score 0):

Most likely its trying to run the migration of adding the password digest to the users table before creating the users table. You can try to create the database first or try resetting it. You can create db by doing rake db:create